# Ghostscript color converting of selected pages but output of all pages

Tags: ghostscript

I want to convert some pages in a PDF to grayscale
I can use the ghostscript option -sPageList to select the desired pages.
But the output contains only the selected pages.

How can I get the whole PDF including the converted pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in one pass with Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device.

The colour conversion options are applied to all the selected output pages, so you need to start by using the PagesList to output the pages you want colour converted. You can use the '%d' format specifier to get each page as a separate file. You can then 'split' the pages you didn't colour convert from the original file by doing the 'opposite' PagesList and using %d again to get each page in a separate file.

Now you have each page as a separate PDF file, some colour converted, some not.

Finally you can feed Ghostscript with each of the PDF files, in the desired order, to create a new PDF file which contains all the pages in the order you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had been concerned that you suggestion is the only way for that problem. Is it possible to get the real (old) page numbers with '%d'? Because after a renumbering of the two new files it seems to be more complicated to combine the two files correctly.

Comment: No, its not possible to have the files named with the original page numbers. The output device doesn't even know what the original page numbers were, it simply sees a sequence of pages. Of course you could **start** by splitting the file, that would get you each page with the original number. Then you can process the pages you want, one by one, giveing them an output name based on the input name, then stitch them all back together

Comment: Thanks. I can now work with this idea. Indeed the file size is grown a lost this way because of the lot of single files. Is there a way to shrink the file size after combining or in a other way?

Comment: Without seeing the file(s) I can't comment. I wouldn't expect a large increase, but its possible if you are reusing the same font on each page, you might end up with a lot of different subsets. You could try setting -dSubsetFotns=false.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @KenS for the clarification.

Here's a Python script that does all this: https://gist.github.com/michaelosthege/a6cc9556ff4e2b64d5f7d3aaee43be70

→ Determinining which pages to convert

→ Extracting each page in colored/grayscale

→ Merging them all back into one PDF